# How to configure default width for left Nautilus column?

Tags: nautilus, 15.10

Is there a way to set the **default width** for the **column** in *Nautilus* which contains *Bookmarks*, *Computer*, *Network*? This should apply to both a plain *Nautilus* windows as well as to an *Open Directory* window.

[image: Nautilus]

Comment: The "Default" width can only be changed in the source.

Answer (score 1):

Use the command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.window-state sidebar-width X
```

where X is the default width in pixels